# Analysis with SPARQL

Tags: sparql, marklogic

I am trying to accomplish some relatively simple analysis with a specific graph.

In Marklogic SPARQL path are created with the following patterns

```
path+ (one or more duplicate path links)
path* (zero or more duplicate path links)
path? (zero or one path link)
path1/path2 (traversing through 2 different links)
```

From here, one analysis I would like to achieve is retrieving all nodes that fulfills a specific condition between node X and node Y. Based on this my query would be something like

```
?nodeX <nodeID> 1
?nodeY <nodeID> 250
?nodeX <nodeLink>* ?nodeY
```

Which does not really seem correct to me, as I don't think this allows me to retrieve the path linking nodeX to nodeY.

I would also like to know if it is possible to do things such as

`Betweeness centrality` which is a measure of the number of times a vertex is found between the shortest path of each vertex pair in a graph.

`Closeness centrality` which is a measure of the distance of one vertex to all other reachable vertices in the graph.

==Update==
Based on the suggestion I have managed to retrieve the path using the following query.

```
?nodeX <nodeID> "1"
?nodeY <nodeID> "250"

?nodeX <nodeLink>* ?v
?v ?p ?u
?u <nodeLink>* ?nodeY
```

When I attempted to do `<p> | !<p>` in my query an error occurred and stating `!` was not a valid expression. However, I believe I can still do the same by using `?path` which will accept any predicate.

Comment: SPARQL is not really designed for graph traversal or graph algorithm. Proper graph databases are way more appropriate and optimized for those things. Given that you can't use variables in property paths, the only workaround is to use a wildcard `(<p>|!<p>)*` or even with incoming edges `((<p>|!<p>)|^(<p>|!<p>))*` and then do `?start <wildcard>* ?u . ?u ?p ?v . ?v <wildcard>* ?end .` - but in case there are multiple paths you'll always get all edges, this can't be avoided and is beyond a single SPARQL query.

Comment: I have attempted your suggestion and managed to got it to work as shown in the codes i used in `==Update==`. However, based on the workaround in `==Update==` for `(<p>|!<p>)*` I would like to ask if it is possible to do `?path|^?path`? Finally, for better efficiency I would like to ask if it is possible to convert the list of sem:bindings into a list of string for me to use `cts:search(fn:doc(list_of_uri), ...)` to do more filtering? I have attempted to convert using `fn:string(..)` and `xs:string(..)` but encountered an error stating `sem:bindings` could not be converted. @AKSW

Comment: uhm, as I said in my previous comment, you **can't use variables in property paths** - that's the only reason for using this workaround `<p>|!<p>` which in fact states that there is a path either via `<p>` or not `<p>` which indeed is always true. I read in the docs now *"The SPARQL modifier ! has not been implemented in MarkLogic. Using this modifier to invert a property path value results in a syntax error."* - but then I have to say that the workaround with the wildcard is not possible - sorry.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this restriction given that it's supposed to be fully SPARQL 1.1 compliant. You could open a feature request or maybe ask on their mailing list for some guidance regarding your task. But I doubt that SPARQL is the appropriate way to go here compared to graph databases with Cypher, Gremlin, whatvever graph query language support.

Comment: Indeed, I might be totally wrong and somebody else here will correct me